# Why does an I inside a span inside a button show up as IJ in Safari

Tags: html, css, safari

I wrote the following code

```
<button>
<span style="font-weight:500;">I</span>
</button>
```

but when I run it on Safari I get a button with `IJ` instead of `I` written on it. It works just fine on Chrome.

## Safari

[image: Safari]

## Chrome

[image: Chrome]

I've noticed this only happens when I have a `span` inside a `button` and the `font-weight` is **exactly** 500. This issue happens whenever there's an I, for example, if the button read `TRY IT NOW` it would show up in my Safari as `TRY IJT NOW`.

I'm running Safari 9.1 (10601.5.8.3).

Comment: This really happens? Strange! Did you check if it's a particular font (that you are using) related issue?

Comment: What's the font you're using? Can you set up an example?

Comment: The default one, my whole HTML code is in the question.

Comment: @fpg1503 No 'IJ' here, just 'I'. What version of Safari are you running?

Comment: @Roy I'm running Safari 9.1 (10601.5.8.3).

Comment: @fpg1503 Unfortunately, I'm running 9.0... Is there any way I can upgrade so I can try to reproduce the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Updating Safari to Version 9.1.1 (11601.6.17) fixes the bug.